# Mask Detection on SSD Networks

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, mask

I want to implement a Mask Detector like Mask RCNN, but based on the SSD Network.

And my two Questions therefor are:

1. Is there any known incompatibility of Mask Detection/Regression with
   SSD Networks? (Because there is none yet, so maybe there are some
   well known problems, which i am currently not aware of, if yes
   please let me know)
2. Is there already an implementation of that in
   any kind? If yes please provide links.

Comment: Did you find anything? I have the same question.